# Unable to run local version of example.com on browser

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, bind

I wished to run example.com on my local test server (Win XP). For this I was able to setup BIND and configured zones for example.com. The local DNS server and local Apache web server both work well. However when I try example.com on browser it takes me to the original example.com not to the local version.

So what am I missing here? Why can't example.com point to the local version in Apache.

zone record for example.com

```
$TTL 3h
example.com. IN SOA ns1.example.com. ns2.example.com. (
                          1        ; Serial
                          3h       ; Refresh after 3 hours
                          1h       ; Retry after 1 hour
                          1w       ; Expire after 1 week
                          1h )     ; Negative caching TTL of 1 hour

;
; Name servers
;
example.com.  IN NS  ns1.example.com.

;
; Addresses for the canonical names
;
localhost      IN A     127.0.0.1
ns1            IN A     192.168.1.2
```

1. ISC BIND service is running.
2. Apache is running.
3. Dig @192.168.1.2 example.com - shows expected results.
4. Changed my primary DNS to 192.168.1.2
5. Not using any proxy. Everything works from the same box. Browser, DNS and Apache.

What to do to make local example.com work?

Update:
I tried - `nslookup example.com` got the following response -

```
;; Got recursion not available from 192.168.1.2, trying next server
Server:         4.2.2.2
Address:        4.2.2.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.com
Address: 208.77.188.166
```

For nslookup 192.168.1.2 I got -

```
;; Got recursion not available from 192.168.1.2, trying next server
;; Got recursion not available from 192.168.1.2, trying next server
Server:         4.2.2.2
Address:        4.2.2.2#53

** server can't find 2.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
```

For `Dig example.com`, I got -

```
; <<>> DiG 9.6.1 <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 494
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.                   IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.            3600    IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. ns2.example.com. 1 10800 3600 604800 3600

;; Query time: 15 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.2#53(192.168.1.2)
;; WHEN: Sat Jul 04 17:05:05 2009
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 73
```

Comment: Typo in the SOA, the second parameter, ns2.example.com in your case, should be a mailbox, for instance hostmaster.example.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it possible that your web browser uses some proxy rather then direct internet connection?

probably not - but still worth asking.

what does your windows **nslookup** say when you fire it up on computer where you use web browser? does it say that 192.168.1.2 is one and only dns server? what happens when you type example.com as query ?

[edit: i'm blind.. this one should fix the problem]
add

```
@ IN A 91.206.245.2
www IN A 91.206.245.2
```

to your bind zone file, change serial number and reload bind.

Comment: Connects directly to internet. I tried this - nslookup example.com, got the following response -

;; Got recursion not available from 192.168.1.2, trying next server
Server:         4.2.2.2
Address:        4.2.2.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.com
Address: 208.77.188.166

Comment: ok - temporarily kick out 4.2.2.2 from your list of dns'es [ if your bind is not accepting recursive queries you'll loose internet access ], then try again nslookup and see if your bind answers nicely.

Comment: I removed 4.2.2.2, so now just have one primary DNS 192.168.1.2 in TCP/IP settings. The internet still works and now nslookup is showing a very different address in place of 4.2.2.2 (from Internet modem I guess)

Comment: I have added Dig example.com response above, if that helps.

Comment: yes - but your client computer still uses 4.2.2.2 - for time of the test remove 4.2.2.2 from list of dns servers and point only to your 192.168.1.2 as resolver.

Comment: see my TCP/IP settings - http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=14o3y8z&s=5 - is it fine?

Comment: they look ok. run in cmd: ipconfig /flushdns, then nslookup again and post the result.

Comment: I just tried ns1.example.com and it worked, I am not sure why it worked, but how can I have example.com working?

Comment: try adding following to your zone file [ and force bind to reload it ]: @ IN A 192.168.1.2

Comment: Tried ipconfig /flushdns but didn't help. Is my Bind config for example.com fine cuz ns1.example.com worked.

Comment: @ IN A 192.168.1.2 - this seems to be working. Now example.com takes me to the local version. However the www.example.com takes me to the internet version. But yeah we got it working, thanks a lot.

Comment: you need to add another line: "www IN A 192.168.1.2" to get www working

Answer (score 2):

The DNS server you just installed and configured (BIND) is an *authoritative* name server. That's fine but you cannot use it as a *recursive* name server, which is what you did when you "Changed my primary DNS to 192.168.1.2". Hence, nslookup's screams "Got recursion not available from 192.168.1.2, trying next server".

An *authoritative* name server is... authoritative for *some* domains (here, `example.com`) but is not a general-purpose resolving server. For that, you need a *recursive* name server.

Two solutions:

1. Make your BIND name server recursive for your local machine. (Basically, it means adding a `recursion yes;` in a *view*, or being sure that your BIND listens only on local IP addresses.) Note that it is bad practice to have a name server being both recursive and authoritative but, for a personal machine used only for tests, it is not a big deal.
2. Tell the regular recursive that it must forwards requests for `example.com` for your machine. I cannot say more, it depends who manages it, what software it runs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with pQd, you may also run a tool such as [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: assuming all happens on the same box [ that is apache, dns server and browser run on 192.168.1.2 ] wireshark will not be helpful. under windows - afaik - you cannot sniff on loopback.

Comment: He would be able to be sure that no request goes to a proxy and that no dns request goes outside.

Comment: I ran wireshark but was not much helpful as I'm directly connected to the internet.

Comment: Running Wireshark for a simple configuration problem is immensely overkill. dig is enough.

Comment: Yep I agree, but when I posted there were not so many info in the question and we were even sure it was a dns problem. Anyway I'm a network guy and network guys (or me at least) love wireshark to troubleshot things running and server on which they can't connect ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using proxy server then for a while disable proxy server and choose connect to internet directly and open example.com. (Do not open www.example.com)

If things work fine with direct connection to Internet option. Then re-enable proxy server and put do not use proxy for

```
127.0.0.1;localhost;.example.com;
```

in firefox or put bypass proxy for

127.0.0.1,localhost,*.example.com

in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to nslookup from the same machine.  My `named.conf.options` looked like this:

```
acl mynetwork {
  fdxx::/112;
};
recursion yes;
allow-recursion { mynetwork; };
```

I'm not sure why, because I thought nslookup requests were going through my ipv6 network anyway.  But adding localhost and localnets solved it for me:

```
acl mynetwork {
  fdxx::/112;
  localnets; localhost;
};
recursion yes;
allow-recursion { mynetwork; };
```